# Do we always have $\mathcal{R}(A'BA) = \mathcal{R}(A'B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ be a $m\times m$ matrix, and the ranks of these two matrices are arbitrary. My question is: do we always have $\mathcal{R}(A'BA) = \mathcal{R}(A'B)$ ? (the symbol $'$ represents the transpose and $\mathcal{R}(.)$ represents the column space.)

It is obvious that it establishes when the matrix $B$ is symmetrical positive definite. How about the most general case (e.g., both two matrices to be rank deficient, the matrix $B$ is not symmetrical)?

Comment: This does not always hold. Consider e.g. $A=B=2\times2$ nilpotent Jordan block. We have $BA=0$ but $A^TB\ne0$.

Comment: That is indeed a counter-example. How about the necessary and sufficient condition ($A$ and $B$ are real matrices)?